# Scala Export/import macro project

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I´ve been googling but I could not find a good documentation.

I create a project with an entry API using macros, but now since I cannot use it even from my own project I need to export it.

Anybody please can point me to a good documentation/blog where explain how to export/import a macro project with intellij?.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. Just build it and use it as a dependency of other projects. If you are using SBT, run command `sbt publishLocal`. Also, you *can* use macros in other modules of a multi-module project, or in tests (if they are defined in main sources).

Comment: just create a jar and import in another project?. That´s it?

Comment: Yes (again, you basically never want to mess around with jars manually, use SBT/Gradle/Maven/whatever instead).

Comment: Sure, I though it needed a special configuration into the AST to work in another project. So it just work as an external library which I need to import my macro object. Mmmmm dont see the point of use macro then XD